# I need on checkbox click two different calender should open with different age restriction

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am running one query i.e. If i select first check box then on input box(I am taking date of birth in the input box field).
So I have requirement like if my age is 45 years then only I can apply for the job, if it is more that 45 then one message "age not valid".
Again If i select second check box then it should accept age less than or equal to 40 only.

so in first input box age limit is 45 and in 2nd its 40.
I have google online and written code that is only working for 1st checkbox, for 2nd checkbox I am unable to validate the data.

```js
$(".answer").hide();
$(".present_emp").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".answer").show();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dateRangePicker')
                .datepicker({
                    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                    startDate: '01/01/1959',
                    endDate: '12/31/1999'
                })
                .on('changeDate', function (e) {
                    // Revalidate the date field
                    $('#dateRangeForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date_of_birth');
                });

            $('#dateRangeForm').formValidation({
                framework: 'bootstrap',
                icon: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    date: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The date is '
                            },
                            date: {
                                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                                min: '01/01/1959',
                                max: '12/31/1999',
                                message: 'The date is not a valid'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    } else {

        $(".answer").hide();
    }
});
$(".answer1").hide();
$(".non_present_emp").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".answer1").show();
    } else {
        $(".answer1").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="question">
   <label for="present_emp">Working in Same Organization</label>
   <input class="present_emp" type="checkbox" name="kuidfc_emp" value="1" />
   <span class="item-text">Yes</span>
   <input class="non_present_emp" type="checkbox" name="non_present_emp" value="0" />
   <span class="item-text">NO</span>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="answer">
   <label for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth:</label>
   <input type="text" name="date_of_birth" id="dateRangePicker" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return onKeyValidate(event,numeric);" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="answer1">
   <label for="date_of_birth1">Date of Birth1:</label>
   <input type="text" name="date_of_birth1" id="dateRangePicker1" maxlength="10"  placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control"/>
</fieldset>
```

It would be very helpful for me if any suggestion or guidance can be provided how to implement this. struggling from 2-3 days on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, in your javascript I see you use `$('#dateRangeForm')` variable but in html they are not added, `onKeyValidate` function is not added either. I think you should add enough to help people better. Second, you use the check box for a condition where only one condition occurs, yes or no. I think it makes more sense to use `<input type="radio">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example should work now.

```js
$(".answer").hide();
$(".answer1").hide();

$(".present_emp").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(".answer").show();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      maxDate: '0',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      yearRange: '-45:+0'
    });
  } else {
    $(".answer").hide();
  }
});

$(".non_present_emp").change(function() {
  $(".answer1").show();
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
      maxDate: '0',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      yearRange: '-40:+0'
    });
  } else {
    $(".answer1").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<fieldset class="question">
  <label for="present_emp">Working in Same Organization</label>
  <input class="present_emp" type="checkbox" name="kuidfc_emp" value="1" />
  <span class="item-text">Yes</span>
  <input class="non_present_emp" type="checkbox" name="non_present_emp" value="0" />
  <span class="item-text">NO</span>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="answer">
  <label for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth:</label>
  <input type="text" name="date_of_birth" id="datepicker" maxlength="10" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="answer1">
  <label for="date_of_birth1">Date of Birth1:</label>
  <input type="text" name="date_of_birth1" id="datepicker1" maxlength="10" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks this is what I was looking for. But by default both the input field should be hidden. If I click YES then "date of birth should box display" and if i uncheck it should hide. And second if i click NO then "date of birth1 should display" and if I uncheck it should be hidden.

Comment: Updated my code example. Now it should work.